# Add a cable connection without passing cables through the wall

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, ethernet

I have a fiber link coming to my apartment, connecting to the "fiber reader" (I don't really know the name of that device) and connected to a WiFi router. 
Problem is, my [Clevo 650SJ laptop](http://net.eurocom.com/download/m250_ServiceManual.pdf) has a crap WiFi receiver, capping my connection to more than 50%.

Is there a way to receive the full WiFi signal or nd route a cable to connect to my laptop?

Passing a cable direct from the router through the walls is not viable, especially that my room is a later addition to the apartment, and I rent this place.

Comment: Easiest solution is to connect to your router using an ethernet cable, or upgrade your wifi card in the laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use [flat Ethernet cable](https://www.walmart.com/ip/SF-Cable-Cat6-UTP-Flat-Ethernet-Cable-35-feet-White/265212964) ([another example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00WD017GQ)) which is designed to be run around door frames, along baseboard, and under carpet. It's available in i-don't-see-it-white and inconspicuous-beige.

2) Get an external USB WiFi adapter; they're small, easy to install, and can work much better.

3) Replace the PCIe WiFi card in your laptop as per pages 2-16 and 2-17 of the [laptop's manual](http://net.eurocom.com/download/m250_ServiceManual.pdf).

4) Maybe there's a loose connection on your laptop's antenna cables where they snap onto the Wireless PCIe card. Try an unplug-replug of the antenna cables and see if reception improves.

5) Is there a mirror between your WiFi router and laptop? The silver or aluminum backing sprayed onto a mirror is a great way to block a signal.

6) Conversely, boost your WiFi signal by putting a reflector behind the WiFi router. Visualize a direct line between where you normally use your laptop and where the WiFi router is. Extend that line off the back side of the WiFi Router. Put a [home made aluminum foil reflector](https://www.google.com/search?q=wifi%20reflector) there, so the signal which would normally leave your apartment instead bounces towards you.

Comment: its a Clevo W650SJ. The flat ethernet sounds like a good idea to get full speed out of my provider

Comment: Super cool, thanks for the effort. I will try some changes to my problem